# Changing text frame color - app. is freezing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, event-dispatch-thread

Okay, so our assignment is to create a Guessing Game where the user inputs a number and the text foreground is supposed to change to either red if it is too high, blue if it is too low, or green if it is exact.

Our teacher has posted code that does that, and it is quite simple and I can understand it. Problem is, when I try to reformat it for what I need I get the `JFrame`, I get the text field where I can input it, but when I click submit it just like freezes. I suppose it has to do with how the action listener is written, but I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciate.

Here's my code, edited so just that specific part is shown"

```
 button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {


                userInput = keyboard.next();

                if(Integer.parseInt(userInput) > randomNumber)
                    {
                        tf.setForeground(Color.red);;
                    }
                    else if(Integer.parseInt(userInput) < randomNumber)
                    {
                        tf.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    }
                    else if(Integer.parseInt(userInput) == randomNumber)
                    {
                        tf.setForeground(Color.green);
                    }

                }
            }
           );
    }
```

Comment: Don't mix console input and GUI input, that's just confusing

Comment: You're still getting info from the console. Again, don't do this.

Answer (score 5):

```
while(true)
```

That's the problem.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Not quite sure how I blocked it, currently just my second semester of learning Java.

Comment: That causes an infinite loop.  The EDT is busy looping, and can do nothing else.

Comment: Well, the thing is, even before it had that while(true) it still did that. I assumed it might help for it to have a true statement.

Comment: Also, for example, this is the code the teacher has to change the textfield color: new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(256);
int g = rand.nextInt(256);
int b = rand.nextInt(256);

Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
tf.setForeground(color);

Comment: *"Well, the thing is, even before it had that while(true) it still did that."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) of the 'before' code.  Note that an MCVE requires imports (which I edited out of the question) as well as a main method to put it on screen.

Comment: @SomeStudent: then you had something else causing your problem. Your main problem as I see it is that your code is written as if this were a linear console program, not an event-driven GUI, and you need to change your code to the latter.

Comment: Hmm, well posting that code in the comments didn't really work too well. Kinda odd using it when on hitting enter it just prints it out. But in short, it has the same action listener layout but it does the following: Instantiaties a random, sets 3 colors giving them a random of 256, then creates a new color, and finally sets the foreground to that randomly generated color.

Comment: The reason behind why I have it written as such is if memory serves me right, our teacher wrote it all in the public class. I suppose I could create methods, but the issue is that I am uncertain as to which ones or if I even need them

Comment: *"Hmm, well posting that code in the comments didn't really work too well."*  That's why we don't put code in comments.  Instead [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28308722/edit). *"I suppose I could create methods"*  O...K  but I don't really see how that relates to anything else we've discussed.

Comment: Well, you mentioned it seems linear, but quite frankly I myself am uncertain by what you meant. Recall, I am only in 1302 the second semester of Java. I am very much a novice

Comment: @SomeStudent: Get your input from a text field or similar component, not from the console (as you would in a linear program). Also you wouldn't use the while loop in an event-driven program. Rather, after a button is pushed, you'd change the state of a variable in the class, and use that state and the user's input into the jtextfields to determine what colors to use.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I think I may be on that path possibly? So when I run it I have my little JFrame open up and I have 2 things: The button that reads "submit guess" and the empty Textfield. When I set it up I had userInput as its parameter so "new JTextFrame(userInput, 20)". I can type in a number, but on click it freezes. Not sure if this explains it more or if I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Removed the while loop. Literally all I did, and I do think I mentioned in the comments that I removed it.

Comment: @SomeStudent: to ***NOT USE THE SCANNER OBJECT***. Again, get user input from JTextFields. Clear?